# Changing content with CSS keyframe animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using `content:'text';` to **change the text of a div using keyframes** but the div remains empty and nothing changes.

The text inside `#neon-sign` div is not changing and it remains empty :

```css
#neon-sign {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12em;
  color: var(--accent-color);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  line-height: 0.80em;
  font-family: 'Warnes', cursive;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0 linear-gradient(transparent, #ff6f150e);
  animation: changetext infinite 8s, neonanimate 5s linear infinite;
  font-weight: 300;
  content: '';
}

@keyframes changetext {
  0% {
    content: 'Hola';
  }
  20% {
    content: 'Hello';
  }
  40% {
    content: 'Salut';
  }
  60% {
    content: 'Ciao';
  }
  80% {
    content: 'Привет';
  }
  100% {
    content: '你好';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="neon-sign"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property works with pseudo elements (`::before` or `::after`). You need to apply it like in this example (I simplified your CSS) :

```css
#neon-sign::before {
  font-size: 12em;
  font-family: 'Warnes', cursive;
  animation: changetext infinite 8s;
  content: '';
}

@keyframes changetext {
  0% { content: 'Hola'; }
  20% { content: 'Hello'; }
  40% { content: 'Salut'; }
  60% { content: 'Ciao'; }
  80% { content: 'Привет'; }
  100% { content: '你好'; }
}
```

```html
<div id="neon-sign"></div>
```

You should also note that :

> CSS-generated content is not included in the DOM. Because of this, it
> will not be represented in the accessibility tree and certain
> assistive technology/browser combinations will not announce it. If the
> content conveys information that is critical to understanding the
> page's purpose, it is better to include it in the main document.

[Source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#accessibility_concerns)

If you believe the content should be accessible, this is not the best approach.